# neo4j Optimize a relationsship check (query)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relation

after importing data via CSV LOAD I want to connect the imported nodes to customer nodes that are already in the DB. The idea was to look up all imported nodes with the Label TICKET and run through the result set and create the relationship.

Here is the code I come up with first approach:

```
# Find nodes without relationship for label Ticket
MATCH (t:Ticket), (c:Customer) 
WHERE NOT (t)--(c) 
RETURN t.number as ticket_number, t.type as ticket_type,t.sid as ticket_sid

# Run through the resultset and execute for each found node
MATCH (t:Ticket { number: "xxx" }), (c:Customer {code: "xxx"})      
MERGE (t)-[:IS_TICKET_OF]->(c);
```

There is an index 
ON :Ticket (number)
ON :Customer(code)

This way to handle it is very slow and it took minutes to run through the CSV file. I hope there is a way to optimize the query or maybe to find a way to create the missing relationship easier as first to look them all up and then run through a loop.

The CSV Load is :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:c:..." AS csvLine
MERGE (t:Ticket { number: csvLine[0]})
```

Maybe its also fine to create the relation already in the CSV import - maybe something like

```
MATCH (c:Customer {code:"xxx"}) 
MERGE (t) - [:IS_TICKET_OF]-> (c)
```

But I would need to figure out in the query how to extract the code from a field as I have something like "aaa/vvv/bbb/1234" in the CSV import and would need only aaa for the match above as this is stored in the customer node as ID.

Any hint is very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this query work for you?

It stores the `aaa` part of the input string in `num`, makes sure the ticket with that number exists, and then makes sure a relationship exists to the matching customer (if there is such a customer).

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:c:..." AS csvLine
WITH SPLIT(csvLine[0], '/')[0] AS num
MERGE (t:Ticket {number: num})
WITH num, t
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Customer {code: num})
MERGE (t)-[:IS_TICKET_OF]->(c);
```